# Failed to load configuration of your project - React Native 0.70.5

Tags: react-native, expo

After upgrading my react-native version from `0.68.5` to `0.70.5`. I am constantly getting this error on starting the JS bundler.

[image]

I have tried multiple things like upgrading the `@react-native-community/cli` version in my package.json file, etc. But nothing worked.

Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli` try to remove all global pkj

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because the `react-native` CLI was reading a `package.json` file in a parent directory (from where the command was being executed) making it think it was already a React Native project. Deleting the following files made the error go away (in Windows):

> C:\Users\<Name>\package.json
> C:\Users\<Name>\yarn.lock